# Django synchronous function: wait for one session to finishing using function

Tags: python, django, asynchronous, server, queue

In my django server, I have a function that handles a request from a user. When multiple users are sending requests from within their respective sessions at the same time, the function processes the requests within their own sessions so it happens in parallel. But I want to ensure that when I have multiple requests from multiple users, they are handled one by one rather than simultaneously. Basically, I don't want this function to be a session instance but a global function that only one user can use at a time. How can I solve this problem? This is an open-ended question so as long as we are using Django in the implementation I don't have any more constraints.

Comment: Hi Prionti, I think this is in Django's nature to run concurrently, and going against that is probably (not definitely) the wrong solution to whatever your problem is. Talking design/architecture is outside the scope here but I'd say to just double check this is what you really need. For example, if you only want to allow one user access to a resource at a time, maybe some sort of lock or semaphore would be more appropriate

Comment: You can use queue based approach by implementing celery with Django. But you might need to change your design in maintaing requests, like in a model or any other approach. For processing requests asynchronously, celery would be a best option.